# invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today downloaded the studio 3.0 beta 2.0 version, after that tried to open an existing project in it and faced some difficulties, most of them I could solve with the help of Google and Stack Overflow, but this one I can not.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
```

Also posting my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.intersoft.snappy"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypeMatching 'dev', 'debug'
buildTypeMatching 'qa', 'debug'
buildTypeMatching 'rc', 'release'
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] 
} }
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
mavenLocal()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/ashokslsk/CheckableView' }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

}
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.1'
implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.piotrek1543:CustomSpinner:0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
implementation 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
implementation project(':sandriosCamera')
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
}

afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
}
}
subprojects {
project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
    if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
        project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
    } else if 
("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
        project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
```

also my another module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
}
}

group = 'com.sandrios.android'
version = '1.0.8'

ext {
PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.sandrios.android'
PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'sandriosCamera'
PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0.8'
PUBLISH_CODE = 9
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode PUBLISH_CODE
    versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classifier 'sources'
}

task generateJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
failOnError false
source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
        .join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task generateJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
from generateJavadocs.destinationDir
classifier 'javadoc'
}

generateJavadocsJar.dependsOn generateJavadocs

artifacts {
archives generateSourcesJar
archives generateJavadocsJar
}

install {
repositories.mavenInstaller {
    pom.project {
        name PUBLISH_GROUP_ID
        description 'Simple integration of universal camera in android for easy image and video capture.'
        url 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera'
        inceptionYear '2016'

        packaging 'aar'
        version PUBLISH_VERSION

        scm {
            connection 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera.git'
            url 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera'

        }
        developers {
            developer {
                name 'arpitgandhi9'
            }
        }
    }
}
}

bintray {
Properties properties = new Properties()

properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
user = properties.getProperty('bintray.user')
key = properties.getProperty('bintray.apikey')
configurations = ['archives']
pkg {
    repo = 'android'
    name = 'sandriosCamera'
    userOrg = 'sandriosstudios'
    desc = 'Android solution to simplify work with different camera apis.'
    licenses = ['MIT']
    labels = ['android', 'camera', 'photo', 'video']
    websiteUrl = 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera'
    issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera/issues'
    vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/sandrios/sandriosCamera.git'
    version {
        name = PUBLISH_VERSION
        vcsTag = PUBLISH_VERSION
        desc = 'Minor fixes.'
        released = new Date()
    }
}
}

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.2'
}
```

and also project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

please help me to get rid of this error

Comment: please post your gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 3.0 only alpha and beta as I know

Comment: @ShaifaliPundir I did not posted the gradle-wrapper.properties as I was quite confident it was not related to that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found my answer, for me personally it was using

```
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"
```

Instead of

```
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android"
```

Comment: IMHO: Using Guava in Android app is bad solution

Comment: Too fat library. It will force to use multidex. if you want to use one or two classes from Guava - extract only these classes and put to your app

Comment: it worked, but can you explain it a bit? @TheHebrewHammer

Comment: Sure, staying in guava 22 (I think) they started using JDK 1.8 features which aren't available until API 24 (in guava 23 there are some language features that aren't available until 26 which is why you're seeing the error). When they did that they split the library to support older Android APIs. So, guava-android is locked to JDk 1.7.

Answer (score 83):

It is important part:

You need to add this in that module's build.gradle where it's not added like app module.

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Also you forgot to add repo for plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure he can't use Java 1.8 because his min SDK is 19. I'm having the same issue. Also, I tried doing this and the error persists.

Comment: I'm using this with min SDK 15. Gradle Plugin 2.4+ run `desugar` for code and you can check `lambda support` at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Android plugin v3 will take Java 8 code and produce compatible Dex based on min SDK version. It does support Java 8 language constructs, but not new API such as java.time.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0-beta2 it only worked when I switched to guava's Android version which uses java 1.7

Comment: Thank you!  In my case, a library uses JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, but the project using the library did not have it in build.gradle.  Adding it solved the problem instantly.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same errors(`SimException`) that you encountered. I had 3 modules in android clean architecture project:

- data(android library)
- domain(plain java module)
- presentation(app - all android stuff)

*solution*

navigate to `File/Project Structure...`

make sure your modules has the same Source and Target Compatibility (1.8 in this case)

Comment: Even kotlin modules require the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to be set now when the java library module is using 1.8. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I was getting a similar error when trying to compile Scala for Android and this just fixed it for that also.

Answer (score 14):

I added a library with the `compileOptions Java 1.8`, and In my main project dont.
Fixed adding:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: Same issue for me, adding it fix the problem

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. I had recently deleted my `.gradle` cache folder, and reinstalled Android Studio and the SDK. Eventually when trying to `git bisect` the problem, it went away. I can only speculate as to why this happened, but I suspect that downloading older versions of the build tools and SDK, and building (and presumably caching) versions of our code with those older tools caused it to be built in a way that didn't cause issues.

This points to some sort of bug in the way that the newer (API 26?) build tools are building the source code, and so my recommendation if you're seeing this problem and the other solutions don't work, is to lower your target SDK version to 25 or lower, install the necessary build tools, and try compiling your code with those, before reverting to build tools 26 or higher.