# Library works in IntelliJ doesn't but doesn't work in Android studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, stanford-nlp, libraries

I have java project based on **Stanford Natural Language Processing** libraries, which i want to redo in android studio, the libraries are causing issues. does anyone know how to import natural language processing library Stanford CoreNLP to android studio?

I've googled it, there doesn't seem to be a solution for this yet.

i have imported NLP libraries, and added them to android studio gradle file, i get this error when i run the app. [Github link](https://github.com/amirdora/StanfordCoreNLP) This is a sample test app, just making libraries work and then i'll add them to main project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Android SDK to version 26 or higher, and make sure Android Studio is using it.

Comment: I have updated android studio current version is 3.0.1 also using compileSdkVersion 26.

Comment: @AmirDe, what is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: minSdkVersion was 15, i updated it to 23 now and still i get same error.

Comment: @AmirDe, read your errors. Always. It clearly says that minimum required `minSdkVersion` value is 26. Where did 23 even came from?

Comment: if that didn't work, try the answers in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862140/invokedynamic-requires-min-sdk-version-26